# Modules imported upon class intiation can't be used by methods

Tags: python, pdfminer

I've created a class that import some modules upon intiation and then these modules are used in some class methods. When I call the modules in a method, I get a NameError that these models are not defined

```
class Paper(object):
    '''
    analyse a paper and extract parts of it
    '''
    def __init__(self, paper_path):

        #import needed modules
        needed_modules = ['io', 'pdfminer', 'pickle', 're', 'string', 'os']
        import io, pickle, re, string, os

        from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter as TC
        from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter as PInt
        from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager as RM
        from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage as Page
        from pdfminer.layout import LAParams as LAP

        self._pPath = paper_path


    def get_text(self):
        res_manager = RM()
        fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
        codec = 'utf-8'
        laparams = LAP()
        converter = TextConverter(res_manager,
        fake_file_handle,codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
        page_interpreter = PInt(res_manager, converter)

        with open(self._pPath, 'rb') as fh:
            for page in Page.get_pages(fh,
                                          caching=True,
                                          check_extractable=True):
                page_interpreter.process_page(page)

            text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()

        # close open handles
        converter.close()
        fake_file_handle.close()

        if text:
            return text
```

When a run this code:

```
pPath = 'path'

item = Paper(pPath)
print(len(item.get_text()))
```

I get the following error

```
NameError: name 'RM' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the modules are created as local objects within the init function. If you would move your import statements to the outside of your initialization method, it should work. It is common to just to the imports all the way at the top of your python file (outside any method)

Comment: I had seen code from popular tools that do `import` only locally inside functions. But in that case the package is only used within the function and cannot be accessed outside it.

Comment: I've moved all the imports up before `def.__init__(self)` but still get the same error!

Comment: Try and move them even outside the Class definition. Often the import lines are simply the very first lines of a *.py document. There is no reason not to have them as a global.

Answer (score 0):

As Harm says: the imports are local to your `__init__` method. You need to move them higher up or store them into some variable to then update into `locals()` in each method.

A very ugly hack:

```
def __init__(self, paper_path):
    ...
    self.imports = locals()  # possibly only include the imports, not the entire dict

def get_text(self):
    locals().update(self.locals)
```

Comment: I've tried what @Harm said but I still get the same error

Comment: You did not: move all the `from x import y as z`statements to somewhere ABOVE the `class Paper(object):` line. You will definitely not get this error then.

Comment: as far as I understand Harm meant to move `from x import y as z` just below `class paper(object)`. The idea is, I want these libraries to be only imported if this class is used, i.e I don't want them to be global for the whole file

Comment: Then try my ugly hack? I didn't try, but I think class would be parsed on first import so moving them to class level would not do you any good in what you need to achieve.